# Z-Index not working on element with position:relative when its parent is position:absolute

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a page tutorial kind of thing, where divs get highlighted on the page. I have a modal dialog that is ordinarily shown on top of an overlay. However, what I want to do is put the modal dialog behind the overlay but bring a particular div within that modal to the front.

[Here is a JS fiddle of my code](http://jsfiddle.net/PBN2S/).

How do I get the div to appear on top of the overlay?

CSS:

```
    .overlay 
     {  
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        bottom:0;
        z-index:1000;
        background-color:#000000;
        opacity:0.7;    
    }

    .modal
    {    
        position:absolute;
        top:300px;
        left:50%;
        z-index:999;
        overflow:auto;
        margin:-250px 0px 0px -280px;
        border:1px solid #999;
        background-color:#fff;
        border-radius:6px;
        -webkit-border-radius:6px;
        -moz-border-radius:6px;
        -webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow:0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        box-shadow:0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        background-clip:padding-box;
        padding:10px;
    }

    .highlight
    {
        z-index:1002;
        position:relative;
        background-color:#ffffff;
    }

.modal-contents
{
    height:100px;
    min-width:100px;
}



.section
{
    padding:5px;
}
```

html:

```
<body>
    <div class="overlay"></div>       
    <div class="modal">
        <h1>Modal Window</h1>
        <div class="modal-contents">
            <div class="section highlight">
                This div should be highlighted above the overlay!
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                This is section two
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>       
</body>
```

Comment: Put z-index:6 to overlay.

Comment: @nevermind, read the question.

Comment: Erm, yeah that just brings the modal to the front?

Comment: you can't - the fact that overlay is on the same level as modal means either modal will be on top or overlay will - unless you use javascript

Comment: @DavidMasters, you can only manipulate z-indexes on the same root element. If you really need the highlighted element to be above the overlay, you'll need to use absolute positioning and set it to the same root element as `.overlay`, and then increase its z-index accordingly.

Comment: Imo, you cant do that! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FUnderstanding_z-index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove all z-index values and the white background for the modal element
http://jsfiddle.net/TfSa5/

```
 .overlay 
 {  
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;

background-color:#000000;
opacity:0.7;    
}

.modal
{    
position:absolute;
top:300px;
left:50%;

overflow:auto;
margin:-250px 0px 0px -280px;
border:1px solid #999;
border-radius:6px;
-webkit-border-radius:6px;
-moz-border-radius:6px;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-moz-box-shadow:0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
box-shadow:0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
background-clip:padding-box;
padding:10px;
}

.modal-contents
{
height:100px;
min-width:100px;
}

.highlight
{
position:relative;
background-color:#ffffff;
}

.section
{
padding:5px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I'd like an explanation too, because I've just tested it and it works :)

Comment: but be careful if you wanted the overlay to prevent clicks on the elements behind it, this will not work! Technically the overlay is behind the rest.

Comment: The question states to bring the highlighted element on top of the overlay. And in the natural order without the z-index it is.